# Is it possible to read environment variables from php?

Tags: php

The environment variable logonserver is available from the cmd prompt

```
echo %logonserver%
```

Is it possible to read this variable from php which will be accessed via a browser and not the cmd prompt, which means I can't pass the value in as a parameter.

I know I could shell out to cmd and get it that way, but I was wondering if there was some built-in php functionality for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. All environment variables are accessible through super-global `$_SERVER` variable. Just try `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what's inside.